# how to use in clause into inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need a query like that ;

```
select a.*, b.column1 from table1 a
inner join table2 b on (b.id in (id_array))
```

This query returns nothing.

What I want to do: I retrieve the group of ids from table1.Then get the name column of these ids from table2. So, I use inner join for this.

Comment: what is the datatype of `a.ids`? is it an array? is it a text csv?

Comment: Please show some sample data.

Comment: @Bohemian yes a.ids is array. I changed the query now. it's better now.

Comment: @YasinYörük well my answer should work then

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't just be the join?

```
select a.*, b.* from table1 a
inner join table2 b on b.id = a.id
```

Comment: who can say without seeing schema, although the question suggests some kind of id *list*

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table1, table2
where find_in_set(id, ids) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* , b.* from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `a.ids` is some kind of id list, so you could use the [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
select * 
from table1 a
join table2 b on find_in_set(b.id, a.ids) > 0
```